# Remove "Updates" link from Wordpress Admin Dashboard

Tags: wordpress

Does anyone knows how to remove the menu link named "Updates", found under the "Dashboard" section of the Wordpress Administration Menu?

I added the following actions & filters, which stop the core, theme & plugins updates, but the menu link is still there, although there is nothing to update:

```
# Disable WP>3.0 core updates
add_filter( 'pre_site_transient_update_core', create_function( '$a', "return null;" ) );

# Disable WP>3.0 plugin updates
remove_action( 'load-update-core.php', 'wp_update_plugins' );
add_filter( 'pre_site_transient_update_plugins', create_function( '$a', "return null;" ) );

# Disable WP>3.0 theme updates
remove_action( 'load-update-core.php', 'wp_update_themes' );
add_filter( 'pre_site_transient_update_themes', create_function( '$a', "return null;" ) );

# disable edit plugin and theme files:
define('DISALLOW_FILE_EDIT',true);

# disable core updates:
add_filter( 'pre_site_transient_update_core', create_function( '$a', "return null;" ) );
```

Thank you,

Ciprian

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
function edit_admin_menus() {  
global $submenu;  
unset($submenu['index.php'][10]);
return $submenu;
}  
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'edit_admin_menus' );
```

Put that in your theme's functions.php file or in your plugin code.

Answer (score 4):

@wunderdojo wasn't "wrong", but WordPress has a bit of a better built in mechanism to handle this.

What you want (or anyone else viewing this these days) is a function called `remove_submenu_page`
Codex link: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_submenu_page

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'control_menu_items_shown' );
function control_menu_items_shown() {
    remove_submenu_page( 'index.php', 'update-core.php' );
}
```

`index.php` is the name for the "Dashboard" menu item and `update-core.php` is the name for the "Updates" menu sub item.

Please note the naming mechanisms of these change quite a bit depending on the plugin, theme, etc.

Example from the Mandrill plugin:
`remove_submenu_page( 'options-general.php', 'wpmandrill' );`

They may not end in `.php`

It's also worth noting a similiar function `remove_menu_page`
Codex link: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page

Hope someone finds this useful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

The update options comes in two places in back-end. One as the message on top and second in the 'AT a glance' window in dashboard. Place the below code in your functions.php. This code will hide the update options from these two areas.

```
add_action('admin_menu','wphidenag');
function wphidenag() {
remove_action( 'admin_notices', 'update_nag', 3 );
}
function admin_style() { ?>
  <style>
  #wp-version-message a.button{
  display:none;
  }
  </style>
  <?php 
}
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'admin_style');
```